# How to copy value from a mongo database field to another using ID?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I was wondering if there is a way to copy every value from a data field with a unique "_id" to another using just "_id".

I do know how to update every single value from one database to another by running different commands for each data field such as

`collection.update_one({"_id":13},{"$set":{"skin2":skin1[0]["skin"]}})`

but doing this for every data field will be kinda hectic, so I was wondering if there was a simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: Since I couldn't add images in the post as I have less than 10 reputations, I was talking about achieving something like this https://imgur.com/a/ch0jgCb

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266